# slick grid column (text-align)

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, tablecolumn

Is there any way to align the header in a slick grid to center and the text in the columns to left? any css files need modification or something else?

Please guide.

```
var columns = [ 
  { id: "colEmpId", name: 'Number', field: "EmpId", "unselectable": false }, 
  { id: "colLastName", name: 'Last Name', field: "LastName", "unselectable": false }, 
  { id: "colFirstName", name: 'First Name', field: "FirstName", "unselectable": false } 
];
```

This is column definition

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can style the headings using the built-in classes in the css sheet.: `.slick-header`  `.slick-header-column` `.slick-header-columns` `.slick-headerrow-column` `.slick-headerrow-columns`

For text in the columns you can assign a custom css class in the column definition and add this to your style sheet.

e.g.

```
var columns = [ { id: "colEmpId", name: 'Number', cssClass: "column-empid" },  ...
```